# Interpolated strings from regular string reference

Tags: c#

I have a string that looks like this:

```
string foobar = "foo{bar}";
string bar= "bar";
Console.WriteLine(foobar);
```

is there a pretty way of making foobar a interpolated string after it has been declared?

I know I can do like this, but i don't receive foobar as a interpolated string

```
string bar= "bar";
string foobar= $"foo{bar}";
Console.WriteLine(foobar);
```

or like this, but I wonder if there's a prettier way of doing it

```
string foobar = "foo{bar}";
string bar= "bar";
Console.WriteLine(foobar.Replace("{bar}", bar);
```

Comment: String interpolation is a compile time language feature. You want to use it as a runtime feature. You can use `String.Format`.

Comment: This has already been answered and can't be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String Interpolation is compile time only because it relies on the presence of the referenced variables.

https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/c-6-string-interpolation-is-not-a-templating-engine-and-it-s-not-the-new-string-format

Use something like this instead:

```
var foo = "foo{0}";
var bar = "bar;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(foo, bar));
```